# Ball valve left half opened

Tags: plumbing

A plumber replaced my water heater last week and he left the main valve half opened.  Is there any good reason for this or he just forgot about it?  Is it safe to put it back fully opened as it was?  The valve model is "Watts regulator FBVS-1".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, no problem to crank it open. You probably won't notice any or much of a difference, ball valves aren't nearly as frugal as knobby compression valves.

Due to your comment's additional information. A harmonic imbalance was created by the valve's position. Therefore, you need to open it more or all of the way to get rid of the sound. Alternatively, you might have to close it down further to remove the sound as well, but we both hope that's not the sound fix, as you've already noticed a slight flow difference.

Comment: -2 because of bad sense of humor or because of bad advice?

Comment: Bad sense of humor. Some don't like to see any humor. Should I take it out? Or, should I move it into 2nd sentence position, though self-explanatory it is kind of in the wrong spot?

Comment: I would consider removing it.  What do you mean by "he knows them better"? BTW, I noticed a small pressure difference since last week and the main valve is now noisy when, for instance, the toilet is flushed.  I hope there won't be any consequences.

Comment: Sounds good, I'll take it out. What I meant by "he knows them better" is that he knows the flow is unrestricted when the valve is just mostly open & not fully open. But, I'll take that out too, since he didn't test it & created a sound issue. You'll have to see if the sound goes away with opening the valve fully or by even closing it further. The sound is a harmonic imbalance & only playing with the valve will remove it.

Comment: Thanks, I'll do that.  Do you think the valve can be damaged?  I've heard of debris being caught in the join because of the "abnormal" position of the ball.

Comment: Nope, the valve should be fine. Yep, a ball valve "can" get deposits if the ball is left in the water stream, but the other benefit of ball valves is that those deposits would only affect or limit opening & not at all hinder closing.